# Mistakes in Shnayim Mikrah V'Echad Targum

Tags: halacha, mistakes, shnayim-mikra

A question that's always bothered me: when doing the mitzvah of Shnayim Mikrah V'Echad Targum, how accurate must one be in order to fulfill the mitzvah?

In other words, let's say one mispronounces a word (either in the Hebrew or the Targum) - are you still yotzei?

And if one mispronounces 2 words?  Or leaves an entire word out?  Is it similar to, say, the mitzvah of teffilin, whereby if a single letter is missing the ENTIRE mitzvah is invalid?  Or do we say that there are different levels and one may still fulfill it to a certain degree?

I'm not asking about receiving s'char for learning, which he surely gets.  My question centers specifically on Shnayim Mikra.

Comment: Why would it be any different than *leining* of a congregation? If it changes the meaning he must go back.

Comment: The halachos of kesiva have nothing to do with kriyah.  Certainly you should go back and repeat.  The Mishnah Berurah spells out the criteria.